# Graphviz: Invert two nodes position inside a cluster

Tags: graphviz, image-graphviz

I am trying to inverse the position of two nodes (`producción` & `funciones`) that are inside a cluster (`cluster_fp`). Instead of `producción` on top and `funciones` at bottom, I need `funciones` on top and `producción` at bottom. How can I achieve that? They are in a cluster just because I thought it is the right approach, but probably it isn't. Because my reputation, I can't post images directly, so I leave the links to i.stack.imgur.com.

[image: [IMG] Issue (nodes have to be in an inverse vertical position)]

Code:

```
digraph tríada {
  rankdir=LR;
  edge [arrowhead=none];
  label="* socialmente reconocido";
  labeljust=left;

  subgraph cluster_sinonimia_oa {
    style=dashed;
    label="sinonimia obra-texto";

    subgraph cluster_texto {
      style=striped;
      label=texto;

      selección [shape=rect];
    }

    obra [shape=rect, style=striped];
    supuesto [label="supuesto\nexistencial", shape=plain];
  }

  subgraph cluster_autor {
    style=striped;
    label="autor*";
    
    máquinas [shape=hexagon];

    subgraph cluster_fp {
      label="";
      style=invis;

      funciones [label="atribución o\napropiación", shape=plain];
      producción [shape=plain];
    }

    subgraph cluster_sinonimia_nepa {
      style=dashed;
      label="sinonimia nombre-entidad-persona-autor";

      personas [shape=hexagon];
      entidad [shape=rect];
      real [shape=diamond];
      ficticia [shape=diamond];
      nula [shape=diamond];
      denotación [shape=plain];
      nombre [shape=rect];
    }
  }

  {personas máquinas} -> real [arrowhead=normal];
  {real ficticia nula} -> entidad [arrowhead=normal];
  nombre -> funciones -> obra -> supuesto -> selección -> producción -> entidad -> denotación -> nombre;
}
```

[image: [IMG] Graph image output]

[Live on dreampuf.github.io](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20tr%C3%ADada%20%7B%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0A%20%20edge%20%5Barrowhead%3Dnone%5D%3B%0A%20%20label%3D%22*%20socialmente%20reconocido%22%3B%0A%20%20labeljust%3Dleft%3B%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_sinonimia_oa%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20style%3Ddashed%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%3D%22sinonimia%20obra-texto%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_texto%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dstriped%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3Dtexto%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20selecci%C3%B3n%20%5Bshape%3Drect%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20obra%20%5Bshape%3Drect%2C%20style%3Dstriped%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20supuesto%20%5Blabel%3D%22supuesto%5Cnexistencial%22%2C%20shape%3Dplain%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_autor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20style%3Dstriped%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%3D%22autor*%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20m%C3%A1quinas%20%5Bshape%3Dhexagon%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_fp%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dinvis%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20funciones%20%5Blabel%3D%22atribuci%C3%B3n%20o%5Cnapropiaci%C3%B3n%22%2C%20shape%3Dplain%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20producci%C3%B3n%20%5Bshape%3Dplain%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_sinonimia_nepa%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Ddashed%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22sinonimia%20nombre-entidad-persona-autor%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20personas%20%5Bshape%3Dhexagon%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20entidad%20%5Bshape%3Drect%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20real%20%5Bshape%3Ddiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ficticia%20%5Bshape%3Ddiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nula%20%5Bshape%3Ddiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20denotaci%C3%B3n%20%5Bshape%3Dplain%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nombre%20%5Bshape%3Drect%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%7Bpersonas%20m%C3%A1quinas%7D%20-%3E%20real%20%5Barrowhead%3Dnormal%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7Breal%20ficticia%20nula%7D%20-%3E%20entidad%20%5Barrowhead%3Dnormal%5D%3B%0A%20%20nombre%20-%3E%20funciones%20-%3E%20obra%20-%3E%20supuesto%20-%3E%20selecci%C3%B3n%20-%3E%20producci%C3%B3n%20-%3E%20entidad%20-%3E%20denotaci%C3%B3n%20-%3E%20nombre%3B%0A%7D)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on lots of experiments, the problem seems to be that **dot**'s algorithm "weights" a multi-node edge more than a two-node edge.
Here is a much-edited input file that produces your desired output:

```
digraph tríada {
  rankdir=LR;
  edge [arrowhead=none];
  label="* socialmente reconocido";
  labeljust=left;

  subgraph cluster_autor {
    style=striped;
    label="autor*";

    subgraph cluster_sinonimia_nepa {
      style=dashed;
      label="sinonimia nombre-entidad-persona-autor";

      personas [shape=hexagon];
      entidad [shape=rect];
      real [shape=diamond];
      ficticia [shape=diamond];
      nula [shape=diamond];
      denotación [shape=plain];
      nombre [shape=rect];
      node [label="" shape=point width=.01] 
      // bogus1 & bogus2 are needed to flip/swap/invert the funciones & producción nodes
      bogus1  bogus2
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_fp {
      label="";
      style=invis;
      funciones [label="atribución o\napropiación", shape=plain];
      producción [shape=plain];
    }

    máquinas [shape=hexagon];

    {personas máquinas} -> real [arrowhead=normal];
    {real ficticia nula} -> entidad [arrowhead=normal];
    entidad -> denotación ->  nombre
  }

  subgraph cluster_sinonimia_oa {
    style=dashed;
    label="sinonimia obra-texto";

    subgraph cluster_texto {
      style=striped;
      label=texto;
      selección [shape=rect];
    }
    obra [shape=rect, style=striped];
    supuesto [label="supuesto\nexistencial", shape=plain];
  }

  nombre -> funciones -> obra -> supuesto -> selección

  producción -> selección  
  entidad -> bogus1 [headclip=false ]
  bogus1 -> bogus2 [tailclip=false, headclip=false]
  bogus2 -> producción [tailclip=false]
}
```

[image]

(Yes, most of the edits were unnecessary)